# apt-get permission denied

Tags: debian, apt

I recently built a new machine, using Debian Jessie. Soon after I upgraded  to stretch, and everything seems fine except, one stubborn error which keeps popping up when I run "apt-get update".

```
Err:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free Translation-en ***Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_stretch_updates_non-free_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]****
```

and finally

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_stretch_updates_non-free_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]
```

At the time there was little advice about how the file should be formed, I simply took my existing *sources.list*, and replaced any mention of "*Jessie*" with "*Stretch*"

Can anyone pitch in with ideas?

Comment: are you running this as root, or with `sudo`?   or are you running it as your non-root user?

Comment: @cas If I remember right sudo is not installed by default in Debian. You can `su -` enter your password and then you can run   `apt-get update` . Either way that command must be run with root privileges.

Comment: yeah, that's why i phrased my question the way i did.  running `apt-get` as root is the important thing, sudo is just one way of doing that.

Comment: `ls -al /var/lib/apt/lists/partial`

Answer (score 7):

So the solution is to remove the content of the `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` as root (just the content not the directory)

```
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

and after do this command :

```
apt-get update
```

tell us if the problem persist ;).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but...What I need to say is too long for a comment, so I added a new answer, Is that the right way to do it? seems overcomplicated to me =)

Comment: i add a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok problem solved, and interestingly enough has uncovered a problem I didn't even know I had.

After making a copy of all of the "lists" directory, I deleted all of the contents (including the "partial" folder), re-ran apt-get update and voila, no errors.

And the bonus issue solved, was the fact that for some time, when I had run apt-get upgrade, it was coming back no updates to apply. I thought nothing of it, only that the teams might be a little slack. However now when I try the "upgrade" I am getting a healthy number of updates coming through.

Many thanks for your help. Might not seem it, but as usual ll it took was the input of a 3rd party, to help trigger a response I hadn't come to on my own. Who'd have thunk it, the system works!! =)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

im sorry if this is not in the correct place (ie answering my own question with an update, but it was too long for a "comment", and I did not want to edit the previous answer, anywhoo here we go...

Thanks for your reply.
First I tried to rm using sudo as advised, but got permission denied. Then was able to cd up to the "/var/lib/apt/lists/" directory, but no further.
So using "su" I could cd into the "partial" directory and run "rm ./*", clearing out the contents.

Re-running "apt-get update" (as root... sigh*) first gave me

```
Ign:13 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free Translation-en
Hit:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Err:13 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free Translation-en
  BZ2_bzread: /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_stretch_updates_non-free_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 Read error (-5: DATA_ERROR_MAGIC)
Ign:14 tor+http://zcaptnv5ljsxpnjt.onion jessie InRelease
Hit:15 tor+http://zcaptnv5ljsxpnjt.onion jessie Release
Fetched 295 kB in 2s (130 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  BZ2_bzread: /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_stretch_updates_non-free_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 Read error (-5: DATA_ERROR_MAGIC)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The running update again gave me the same error as before...

```
Ign:13 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Err:13 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free Translation-en
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_stretch_updates_non-free_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 195.20.242.89 80]
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Fetched 62.9 kB in 1s (43.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_stretch_updates_non-free_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 195.20.242.89 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is the directory entry for my "partial" directory, are the permissions the same for everyone else?

```
drwx------ 2 _apt root    16384 Aug  5 15:41 partial
```

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: In Debian there is normally no sandboxuser _apt.  But to be sure show  `apt-config dump | grep -i sand
` Edit your question for that.

Comment: for the rights i have `drwxr-xr-x root root` (755 root:root) for partial directory. 
try to remove the content of `lists` and `partial` and change rights and owners and after execute `apt-get update` you can always do a backup of the directory if you want befor removing.

Comment: It would seem that the _apt user has been introduced in the newer version of apt for sandboxing (I guess?)

Comment: i had upgrade my Wheezy to Jessie, and that was my rights and owner for the `partial` directory, this type of error can hapend when you break a process of update, and it's solved by removing the content of lists and partial directory folowed by the execution `apt-get update` or `apt update` of curse as a super user. try to do the both process

Comment: yep that's exactly what solved it, see my answer above. Many thanks for your time =)

Comment: So Voila, Happy For you, ther is no place better than Community Site to solve Problems of Debian, and it's My Favorite Distribution.